# How to create an array in an array, then check if it contains a string. (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

What's the correct way of creating an array of strings, and have lots of them in a array?
So far I tried this

```
 var arrayInArray = [[String]]()
```

Then I appended string arrays into "arrayInArray". And tried checking if it contained a specific string by doing

```
if arrayInArray[indexPath.row].containsObject(PFUser.currentUser().username)
```

and the error is [(String)] does not have a member named 'containsObject'.
Whats the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Can you show where you "appended string arrays into 'arrayInArray'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
var arrayInArray = [[String]]()
arrayInArray += [["Hey", "Ho"]]
arrayInArray += [["Yo", "Yeah"]]
let ix = find(arrayInArray[0], "Ho") // Optional(1), the right answer
```

Or `contains`:

```
let ok = contains(arrayInArray[0], "Ho") // true, the right answer
```

Comment: Matt, where is "contains" documented? I didn't see that in the "The Swift Programming Language" or the "Swift Standard Library Reference". Did I just miss it?

Comment: @rdelmar There is a lot more great stuff in the Swift header than Apple has bothered to write up (so far). That's the real place to learn what you can say - and to understand how Swift built-in object types really work. To get there, say `import Swift` and command-click on `Swift`. "now the ears of my ears awake and now the eyes of my eyes are opened"

Comment: Thanks for that tip; that's great. Hopefully, Apple will get around to updating their docs soon.

Comment: @rdelmar Forgot to mention there is also some good stuff in the CoreGraphics header.